# Successfully overrode document.getElementsByTagName, but not Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to create a program that overrides the `getElementsByTagName()` method. To do so, I attempted to override both `document.getElementsByTagName()` (*Case 1*) and `[x].getElementsByTagName()` (*Case 2*), where `[x]` is any DOM element object. **Problem**: I'm able to successfully override *Case 1*, but not *Case 2*.

Here's the approach I took ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwgKh/1/) - I simplified the code to make it easier to understand). First, to cover for *Case 1*, I overrode `document.getElementsByTagName()` so that calling this method would alert the tag name passed to it, as follows:

```
//Override document.getElementsByTagName
document.oldGetElementsByTagName = document.getElementsByTagName;
document.getElementsByTagName = function(tagName) {
    var theElems = document.oldGetElementsByTagName(tagName);
    alert("The Tag: " + tagName);
    return theElems;
}
```

Next, to handle *Case 2*, I used a similar approach to override `Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName()`, as follows:

```
//Override Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName
Element.prototype.oldGetElementsByTagName = Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName;
Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName = function(tagName) {
    var theElems = Element.prototype.oldGetElementsByTagName(tagName);
    alert("The Tag: " + tagName);
    return theElems;
}
```

Now, let's say the DOM consists of the following:

```
<ul id="something">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```

To test the overridden `document.getElementsByTagName()`, the following is executed...

```
try {
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("li"); //Will be successful
}
catch (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err.message);
}
```

...and it alerts the tag name "`li`", so the method override was successful. To test the overridden `Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName()`, the following is executed...

```
try {
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("something");
    var items = wrapper.getElementsByTagName("li"); //Will lead to error
}
catch (err) {
    alert("Error: " + err.message);
}
```

...but, in this case, the following error message is alerted:

```
Error: 'getElementsByTagName' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
```

What's wrong with the overriding method to `Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName()`?

Comment: [Don't mess with the DOM](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/)! Why do you want to overwrite such methods?

Comment: @Bergi I'm not actually creating a web application, but rather, a DOM statistics tracker that performs a dynamic analysis of DOM method calls, in any given web application X (I'm obviously leaving out a lot of details, but that's the gist of it). I'm still in the experimental stages of developing this stats tracker, so I decided to go with the easiest implementation as a proof-of-concept first (although the idea may evolve later on). I figured the easiest implementation would be to instrument the JS code with the overriding code via a proxy.

Comment: @Bergi I encountered this problem along the way and thought it would be interesting to share the solution I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I was improperly using `Element.prototype` in the overriding method. More specifically, the following code in the overriding method...

```
var theElems = Element.prototype.oldGetElementsByTagName(tagName);
```

...should be replaced with the following...

```
var theElems = this.oldGetElementsByTagName(tagName);
```

See the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwgKh/2/). In essence (if I understand correctly), `Element.prototype.oldGetElementsByTagName` simply defines the object `oldGetElementsByTagName` common to all `Element` objects, and is not intended to be "called", as in a regular function call (if you do so, it would be interpreted as you calling `oldGetElementsByTagName()` on an `Element.prototype` object).

Comment: Yes, you understood this correctly. An alternative to the method syntax would be using [`.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).

Comment: That's right. You can also try `Element.prototype.oldGetElementsByTagName.call(this, tagName)`. By the way you don't need to attach the old method to the prototype anyway. Just use a simple `var`.